# How to get Current Data user on Fluent Form Base the details they fillup?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

```
    <table class ="table table-stripped" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>
                ID
            </th>
            <th>
            form_id
            </th>

            <th>
            submission_id
            </th>

            <th>
            field_name
            </th>

            <th>
            sub_field_name
            </th>
       
        </tr>
        <?php 
        global $wpdb;
        $result = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT * FROM wp_fluentform_entry_details");
        foreach ($result as $print){
            ?>


       
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $print->id;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $print->form_id;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $print->field_name;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $print->sub_field_name;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $print->field_value;?></td>

        </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>

    </table>
```

i need the data on fluent form plugins base on current users, previuously they need to signup by name,address,contact details etc. i need to display to their profile please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need to add the form id in you query

```
 <?php 
    global $wpdb;
    // '4' change to your form id number
    $result = $wpdb->get_results (
        "SELECT * FROM wp_fluentform_entry_details WHERE form_id='4'"
    );
    foreach ($result as $print){
        ...
    }
    ?>
```

and I don't think you are looking in the right table. As far as I know, you need to get the entries from wp_fluentform_submissions.

I think that those details you want to display (if the user register using the Fluent Form) can be found in the "response" column in your table.

I mean that you will need to decode your response:

```
$form_response = json_decode($row->response, true);
```

So your code should look something like this:

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;
    $your_table = 'wp_fluentform_submissions';
    //change for id to your form_id
    $your_query = "SELECT * FROM $your_table WHERE form_id = '4'";
                    
    $result = $wpdb->get_results($your_query, OBJECT);
    rsort($orders);

    foreach ($result as $row) { 
        $form_response = json_decode($row->response, true);?>
   
        <p>
            <?php echo ($form_response["username"]) 
            // or what object key you have in your form ?>
        </p>
        <?php 
    } 
?>
```

Hope that helps